# Nativescript: send e-commerce transaction to GoogleAnalytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics, nativescript

I'm trying to send an Enhanced E-commerce transaction to Google Analytics, but it just won't show up and I'm not getting any errors. This is the code I'm trying (one of the versions at least)

```
(global as any).GAITracker.prototype.setValue.call(googleAnalytics.getTracker(), "&cu", price.currency);

const productAction = new (global as any).GAIEcommerceProductAction()
    .setAction('purchase')
    .setTransactionId(this.basket.orderReferenceNumber)
    .setRevenue(price.value);

builder = (global as any).GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().setProductAction(productAction);
    (global as any).GAITracker.prototype.send.call(googleAnalytics.getTracker(), builder.build());
```

I can see other google analytics data coming in, but the transactions just won't work.

For reference, it does work in Android on this code:

```
(googleAnalytics.getTracker() as any).set("&cu", price.currency);

const productAction = new (com as any).google.android.gms.analytics.ecommerce.ProductAction((com as any).google.android.gms.analytics.ecommerce.ProductAction.ACTION_PURCHASE)
    .setTransactionId(this.basket.orderReferenceNumber)
    .setTransactionRevenue(price.value);

builder = new (com as any).google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().setProductAction(productAction);
(googleAnalytics.getTracker() as any).send(builder.build());
```

What do I need to change to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a warning in the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/mobile-implementation-guide) asking new developers to use Firebase SDK instead of Google Analytics SDK for iOS apps.

> Important: New users should use the Firebase SDK to track iOS apps.

You might want to try the Firebase SDK, looks like GA is no longer supported on iOS.